# React useState behaviour , questions on the need of a spread (....) operator

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs, rxjs

why cant I `return expenses1` without spreading it in an array? since expenses1 which is the previous data is an array containing an object? from what i can see, `{listOfExpenses}` takes in an array of objects which is `=== expenses1`

```
import Expenses from "./components/Expenses/Expenses";
import NewExpenses from "./components/NewExpenses/NewExpenses";
import React, { useState } from "react";

const expenses = [
  { id: "e1", title: "Toilet Paper", amount: 94.12, date: new Date(2020, 7, 14),},
  { id: "e2", title: "New TV", amount: 799.49, date: new Date(2021, 2, 12), },
  { id: "e3", title: "Car Insurance", amount: 294.67, date: new Date(2021, 2, 28),},
  { id: "e4", title: "New Desk (Wooden)", amount: 450, date: new Date(2021, 5, 12), },
];

function App() {
  const [listOfExpenses, setListOfExpenses] = useState(expenses);
  const addExpenseHandler = (expenseData) => {
    setListOfExpenses((expenses1) => {
      console.log(expenses1);
      expenses1.push(expenseData);
      console.log(...expenses1);

      return [...expenses1];
    });
  };

 return (
   <div>
     <NewExpenses onAddExpense={addExpenseHandler} />
     <Expenses expenses={listOfExpenses} />
   </div>
 );
}
```

So I've tried console logging and compare the data difference between expenses1 and listOfExpenses, they are both the same data type thus why the need of spreading in an array?

Comment: What exact error do you get if you don't spread the array?

Comment: the component "<Expenses/>" will not show the updated entries of expenses

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should *never* mutate data structures in React (or Redux or RxJs etc.)

The `.push()` method will mutate the existing array. This means it will update *all references* to that array, including the one internally uses to keep track of what needs to be updated. Since the old array and new array are equal, react won't update.

Instead, you should always make a new array. While the spread operator, which will copy the array will technically work, it's only because the equality operator in JS is not very good. Do do it properly use:

```
setListOfExpenses(expenses=>[...expenses, expenseData])
```

This will create a new array that starts with the original expenses, then adds the `expenseData` to the end. This will never mutate the original array, so properly update in all cases, even for libraries that use proper equality checks.

Comment: ok thank you, this answer makes the most sense. React is always comparing states before n after thus the original reference should not be altered. Now i understand why... i need to create a new array.

Answer (score 3):

> why cant i "return expenses1" without spreading it in an array

Because the first rule of React state is **do not modify state directly**, which includes not modifying the state of objects that are held in state (like arrays), see [the documentation](https://reactjs.org/docs/state-and-lifecycle.html#do-not-modify-state-directly). If you don't return a **different** array than the one in state, React doesn't see a difference, and doesn't necessarily re-render properly.

The code you have that is using spread is still technically incorrect (though largely harmless I suspect), it should be copying the array **before** adding to it (or at the same time), not adding it to the array in state (which mutates it, which you mustn't do). Creating a new array by copying a previous one and adding an element can be done with a single array literal:

```
setListOfExpenses((expenses) => {
    return [...expenses, expenseData];
});
```

or even

```
setListOfExpenses((expenses) => [...expenses, expenseData]);
```